# How to directly stream a file from a remote URL to Google Drive

Tags: node.js, file-upload, stream, google-drive-api

I'm trying to directly upload a file from a remote URL to Google Drive, but I don't want to download the file to my server and then upload it to drive. I also am concerned about keeping the entire file in memory and do the uploading as it will not work for large files.

So what I wanted to do is something like directly streaming the file content to the Google Drive, as Drive API accepts a readstream. For that, I have used fetch as follows.

```js
export async function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(mimeType: string, fileName: string, fileUrl: string) {
    const oauth2Client = getGoogleOAuthClient();

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: getGDriveRefreshTokenByUser()
    })

    const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: oauth2Client
    });

    (fileUrl.substring(0, 5) === "https" ? https : http).get(fileUrl, async res => {
        console.log("test")

        const response = await drive.files.create(
            {
                requestBody: {
                    name: fileName,
                    mimeType,
                },
                media: {
                    mimeType,
                    body: res,
                },
            },
        );

        console.log(response.data);
    })
}
```

How can I verify that the node.js server is actually streaming the file content to the Drive rather than waiting until the full file is downloaded and then uploaded to GDrive at once? Thanks in Advance for all help!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
export async function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(mimeType: string, fileName: string, fileUrl: string) {
  const oauth2Client = getGoogleOAuthClient();

  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: getGDriveRefreshTokenByUser()
  })

  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: oauth2Client
  });

  // I modified the below script.
  (fileUrl.substring(0, 5) === "https" ? https : http).get(
    fileUrl,
    async (res) => {
      res.on("data", async (data) => {
        const response = await drive.files.create({
          requestBody: {
            name: fileName,
            mimeType,
          },
          media: {
            mimeType,
            body: data,
          },
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    }
  );
}
```

- When this script is run, the data is downloaded and the downloaded data is uploaded to Google Drive.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your client of `drive` can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this too didn't work in my case. I tried using the url "http://212.183.159.230/512MB.zip" which has a 512MB file. no console.log inside the response function is printed until the file is fully downloaded it seems.

Comment: @Pavindu Thank you for replying. About your URL of `http://212.183.159.230/512MB.zip`, unfortunately, I cannot download the file. So, I cannot test it. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample URL for testing to download?